# Algebra factorization

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ (k+1)[k/2 + 1] = [(k+1)(k+2)] / 2 $$

can anyone explain why the factorization becomes $$ [(k+1)(k+2)] / 2 $$

Comment: I don't understand the question: why there is suddenly an equality sign in the middle of an expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to the revised question. Observe that the factor $\frac{k}{2}+1=\frac{k+2}{2}$ and the other one is the same on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

I assume $k=2$ is a typo for $k+2$, and trust you to work out why $(k/2)+1=(k+2)/2$.

Comment: Hi all, 

I am revising on induction and this is part of the equation it factorize to.

$$ 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k + (k + 1) = [k(k + 1)/2] + (k + 1) $$  
$$ = (k + 1) [k / 2 + 1] = (k + 1)(k + 2) / 2 $$

Comment: @liangteh: $k/2+1=\frac{k+2}{2}$.